# Spring boot kafka application is not start as console app after upgrading gradle and spring boot version

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, dependency-injection

upgradation details.
Spring boot : 2.2.7-RELEASE to 2.4.6
gradle: 4.10.3 to 6.9.2

build.gradle

```
plugins{
   id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.6'
   id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELESE'
   id 'java'
}
sourceCompatibility ='1.8'

dependency-management{
    import {
    mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:2020.0.4"
    }
}
dependencies{
              implmentation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc'
              implmentation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
              implmentation 'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka'
              implmentation 'org.projectlombok.lombok'
              testImplmentation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
              implmentation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config'
              implmentation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap'
              compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
              implmentation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
              compile(group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-configuaration-processor')
              compile(group: 'com.microsoft.sqlserver', name: 'mssql-jdbc' version: '8.3.1.jre8-preview')
              runtimeOnly 'com.microsoft.sqlserver:mysql-jdbc'
              implmentation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.9.2'
              implmentation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.9.2'
              compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
              compile 'org.projectreactor:reactor-spring'
              implmentation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus'
              implmentation 'javax.mail:mail:1.4'
              testImplmentation 'junit:junit'
              annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
              
}
wrapper{
  distribuationUrl = "https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.9.2-bin"

}
```

main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class,HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
@EnableKafka
@EnableScheduling
public class SpringBootMainClassApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootMainClassApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
server.port=8080
```

Error:
“ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean“.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiM90.jpg)

Code running fine after adding below properties to application.properties.

```
spring.main.web-application-type=none
```

Application is working fine as console app without changing spring.main.web-application-type=none to properties with old version spring boot 2.2.7-RELEASE, Can you please help us to run application without adding new properties?

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine, seems you gradle has lot of errors

Please use this gradle, always love your code as beautiful it could be like a painting :)

```
plugins {
  id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "1.0.11.RELEASE"
  id "org.springframework.boot" version "2.4.6"
  id "java"
}

sourceCompatibility ='1.8'

repositories {
    maven {
      url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:2020.0.4"
    }
}

dependencies
{
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.kafka', name: 'spring-kafka'
    
    implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.9.2'
    implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.9.2'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus'
    implementation 'javax.mail:mail:1.4'
    
    compileOnly group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: '1.18.24'
    compileOnly group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-configuaration-processor'
    compileOnly group: 'com.microsoft.sqlserver', name: 'mssql-jdbc', version: '8.3.1.jre8-preview'
    
    compileOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
    compileOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    compileOnly 'org.projectreactor:reactor-spring'
    
    runtimeOnly 'com.microsoft.sqlserver:mysql-jdbc'
    
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit'
    
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I used the your pasted gradle but still same issue.

Comment: for me it is working fine, may be I am using java 11 and gradle 7 but I don't have your full code, I only put the main file

Comment: Tried with java 11 and gradle 6.9.2, still have same issue

Comment: It works fine after update client custom library.