# Not getting any response and error to invoke actuator and prometheus endpoints

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, prometheus, spring-boot-actuator

### Upgrading spring boot kafka console application spring boot and gradle.

- Spring boot : 2.2.7-RELEASE to 2.4.6
- gradle: 4.10.3 to 6.9.2

build.gradle

```
plugins{
   id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.6'
   id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELESE'
   id 'java'
}
sourceCompatibility ='1.8'

dependency-management{
    import {
    mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:2020.0.4"
    }
}
dependencies{
              implmentation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc'
              implmentation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
              implmentation 'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka'
              implmentation 'org.projectlombok.lombok'
              testImplmentation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
              implmentation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config'
              implmentation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap'
              compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
              implmentation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
              compile(group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-configuaration-processor')
              compile(group: 'com.microsoft.sqlserver', name: 'mssql-jdbc' version: '8.3.1.jre8-preview')
              runtimeOnly 'com.microsoft.sqlserver:mysql-jdbc'
              implmentation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.9.2'
              implmentation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.9.2'
              compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
              compile 'org.projectreactor:reactor-spring'
              implmentation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus'
              implmentation 'javax.mail:mail:1.4'
              testImplmentation 'junit:junit'
              annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
              
}
wrapper{
  distribuationUrl = "https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.9.2-bin"

}
```

Main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class,HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
@EnableKafka
@EnableScheduling
public class SpringBootMainClassApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootMainClassApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Application.properties file

```
server.port=8181
springdoc.show.actuator=true
management.server.port= 9090
management.endpoints.web.base-path=/
management.endpoints.web.path-mapping.prometheus=.metrics
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health,mappings,beans,metrics,prometheus
management.endpoints.beans.enabled=true
management.endpoints.health.show-details=always
management.health.ldap.enabled=false

spring.main.web-application-type=none
```

Application was started fine with older version and without add spring.main.web-application-type=none property, more details to refer [Spring boot kafka application is not start as console app after upgrading gradle and spring boot version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71956396/spring-boot-kafka-application-is-not-start-as-console-app-after-upgrading-gradle)

Now prometheus endpoints are not retuning any response and error, not found any error to app console

Endpoints:

*http://localhost:9090/.metrics*
*http://localhost:9090/health*

We have removed all above management properties and tried to invoke actuator endpoints but there also same issue.

Endpoints:
*http://localhost:8181/actuator/health*
*http://localhost:8181/actuator*

Actuator and Prometheus endpoints were working fine with older version and gradle, Can you please help us in that?

Comment: Can any one suggest anything?

Comment: This issue is resolved after removed spring.main.web-application-type=none from properties. Prometheus and actuator endpoints are exposed to web.